# Jenkins - How to get test results?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to create the following scenario:

One instance running Jenkins server.  It polls repo and if change occurs it spins up a production instance of my app - let's code name this instance APP_INSTANCE.  NOTE: this APP_INSTANCE is NOT a Jenkins slave in any way.  It is literally the production server of a web application.  No Jenkins stuff installed.

Jenkins passes some configs to APP_INSTANCE like BRANCH_NAME.

APP_INSTANCE checks out BRANCH_NAME and runs test suites.

Jenkins polls APP_INSTANCE via ssh to see when test report file is done being generated.

If Jenkins finds test report file, it assumes tests are done and it copies test report file.

This last part is the part I'm stuck on, how to make Jenkins:
1. copy a file from APP_INSTANCE 
2. parse it for test results so it can display them in its web interface.  (I assume the test report format has to be jUnit or some sht, right?)

So am I dumb for trying to build this?

P.S. I'm using AWS and this is all happening in the cloud.

Comment: I guess there's a low chance I'll get an answer on this one.  Here's a simple question, is it traditional to install the entire application stack on Jenkins server so that Jenkins can run all the tests locally?

Comment: What kind of tests you are executing on this application? in what language your application is written?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs

And read this:
[Setup Jenkins to monitor external job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830098/setup-jenkins-to-monitor-external-job)