# How to install jenkins on centos 7 and run external jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have to monitor cronjobs with jenkins.My OS is centos 7 . So how should I install it and monitor an external job  with jenkins.
A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830098/setup-jenkins-to-monitor-external-job) but that is for ubuntu and not centos that's why I have to post a new question

Comment: Jenkins is not for monitoring. Please read the documentation on how to install. Show some efforts before posting here.

Comment: Jenkins can start and monitor external jobs. See this existing question and answer: [Setup Jenkins to monitor external job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830098/setup-jenkins-to-monitor-external-job)